# Android: Making network requests in a fragment, handling config changes

Tags: android, rest, networking, fragment, tablet

Currently in the app I'm working on network requests are made with ASyncTasks inside of **headless retained fragments** (references: [1](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html#headlessfragments) [2](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html#headlessfragments)) to handle device rotation, etc. It feels pretty hacky (aren't Fragments supposed to be "reusable UI components"?) but works as advertised. So far so good.

The problem now is that I'm modifying the app to support tablets which means converting most Activities into Fragments. Currently the Activities that make API calls try to reattach their "worker fragment" after config changes to see if the API call is already in progress or has already completed.

This doesn't work when an Activity is converted to a Fragment because it would be accessing the Fragment Manager of its host activity - which may be hosting more than one fragment!

After some research it looks like I could use nested fragments (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager()) introduced in API 17 to continue with this approach. To me this feels like it's getting a bit out of hand - there must be a simpler way.

Long story short - what's a simple approach to making API calls from fragments that gracefully handles device config changes? I'd imagine most tablet apps out there do this; so if you've built a tablet app, how do you go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Please look up

```
Fragment#setRetainInstanceState(true)
```

this way you can ensure the Fragment is retained across configuration changes.